# How to upload blob object of type video/webm from nodejs to Mongo DB?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, blob

I have to upload video blob object to Mongo DB using NodeJS.
For video i am using video.js https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record
I am sending blob object to NodeJS using Ajax call like below.

```
var file={
  name:'abc',
  data: player.recordedData.video
};
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uploadVideo',
        data: file,
        dataType: 'JSON'

}).done(function(data) {
                alert("success");
});
```

Here file is JSON object i wanted to save in my collection containing other fields like file name,blob data etc. At Node.js end I have below code

```
router.post('/uploadVideo',function (req, res ,next) {
    var file=req.body;
    console.log("file"+file);
    var collection = db.get('test');
                collection.insert(file, function(err, result){
                console.log('video saved in mongo db');
                    res.send(file);
                });

});
```

Console statement in which file object is printed works fine.
But getting 500 error while inserting the JSON in mongo DB collection.

Can anyone provide me a solution for inserting blob in collection? Also let me know if my code has any bug.
Thanks

Comment: Give us the entire error and do something like `console.log(typeof(file))` please.

Comment: when i printed console.log(typeof(file)) it printed String on console.

Comment: I have found it's generally not the best idea to stuff blobs in a database.  It's costlier usually, and also normally requires more work.  Instead, I use the right tool for the right job.  Blobs to bulk storage (e.g. S3, and the database record or document gets a URL reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what middleware are you using? Here is the working sample which uses `multer` and `body-parser`.

**Important piece of code:-**

The form data field name (`uploadfile`) should match. And then read the file from the downloaded location using `fs` and set it in the document that will be inserted into MongoDB collection.

```
upload.single('uploadfile');


insertdata["file"] = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
```

**Form data field name:-**

```
File upload: <input type="file" name="uploadfile"><br>
```

**Full HTML form:-**

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/filesave" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    File upload: <input type="file" name="uploadfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**Working code:-**

```
var express = require('express');
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    fs = require('fs');

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });


var collection, dbObj;
module.exports = {

};

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

var exports = module.exports;

app.post("/filesave", upload.single('uploadfile'), function (req, res) {
    db.open(function (err, success) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("DB connection error");
        } else {
            console.log("DB connection is successful");
            console.log(req.body.username);
            console.log(req.file);
            var insertdata  ={};
            insertdata["username"] = req.body.username;
            insertdata["file"] = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

            db.collection("filesave").insert(insertdata, function (inserr, result) {
                if (inserr) {
                    console.log(inserr);
                    db.close(true);
                    res.json(inserr);
                } else {
                    db.close(true);
                    res.json("Successfully persisted in database");
                }
            });
        }
    })


});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Data saved in MongoDB collection:-**

[image: Binary data saved in Mongo Collection]

Comment: can we use same code for audio and video file upload also?

Comment: Yes, the data is saved as binary. So you can have the same code for both audio and video. However, MongoDB collection has a maximum size of 4 MB for a document. If the data may exceeds 4 MB, you may need to consider using GridFS functionality in MongoDB. Also, while rendering the file, you may need to use correct content-type of the file.